# Infopath dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, javascript, infopath, html

I want to creat a form through InfoPath - In a such a way that, if I select "Yes" option then only I should get text box to add my comments.  Otherwise it should not appear in the feedback form. How to do it ?

Comment: Kindly try below steps or steps mentioned in video & let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Atleast responde here with your resolution, If you found any, apart from given answer. So others can get benefit of it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hide a control based on values on the form**

1. On the form template, click the control that you want to hide.
2. On the **Format** menu, click **Conditional Formatting**.
3. In the **Conditional Formatting** dialog box, click **Add**.
4. Under **If this condition is true**, set the condition that you want. For example, to hide the control that you selected in step 1 only when a certain value is entered into another control on the form template, select that second control in the first box, and then specify the value that will determine whether to hide the control that you selected in step 1.
5. Under **Then apply this formatting**, click **Hide this control**.
6. To save the condition and return to the form template, click **OK** twice.
7. To test your changes, click **Preview** on the **Standard** toolbar, or press CTRL+SHIFT+B.

To get clear idea please check below video.

[Hide label and control on InfoPath 2013 form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=af59LpHiusg)

Comment: Did you manage to achieve your desired output or need any help?

Comment: kindly let us know here instead of asking the same question again.

Comment: Did you got it working for you?