# Creating form with Infopath designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath, designer-workflow, html-form-web-part

How to create form with condition drop down. Like If I click option "Other" then only a text box should appear in the form. How to do it ? Urgent

Like :[image]

If I ans 6th question as "Yes: then only the the "specify" row should appear. How to do it ? Urgent

Comment: Atleast responde here with your resolution, If you found any, apart from given answer. So others can get benefit of it.

Answer (score 1):

> Hide a control based on values on the form
>
> 1. On the form template, click the control that you want to hide.
> 2. On the Format menu, click Conditional Formatting.
> 3. In the Conditional Formatting dialog box, click Add.
> 4. Under If this condition is true, set the condition that you want. For example, to hide the control that you selected in step 1 only when
>      a certain value is entered into another control on the form template,
>      select that second control in the first box, and then specify the
>      value that will determine whether to hide the control that you
>      selected in step 1.
> 5. Under Then apply this formatting, click Hide this control.
> 6. To save the condition and return to the form template, click OK twice.
> 7. To test your changes, click Preview on the Standard toolbar, or press CTRL+SHIFT+B.
>
> To get clear idea please check below video.
>
> [Hide label and control on InfoPath 2013 form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=af59LpHiusg)

Kindly find the same answer at below post.

[Infopath dropdown](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185453/infopath-dropdown/185457#185457)